# Ajax response works after two clicks?

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, xmlhttprequest

I just wrote a basic user-login system where the html page uses javascript to send the ajax request to a servlet which accesses through database.
**Here's the js code**

```
var res;
function getXMLObject()
{
   var xmlHttp = false;
   try {
     xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")  // For Old Microsoft Browsers
   }
   catch (e) {
     try {
       xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")  // For Microsoft IE 6.0+
     }
     catch (e2) {
       xmlHttp = false   // No Browser accepts the XMLHTTP Object then false
     }
   }
   if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
     xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        //For Mozilla, Opera Browsers
   }
   return xmlHttp;  // Mandatory Statement returning the ajax object created
}

var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject();   //xmlhttp holds the ajax object


function handleServerResponse() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {        
               res=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
     else {
                    return false;
        alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again");
     }

}

function ajaxFunction() {
        var veid=document.getElementById("eid").value;
        var vpwd=document.getElementById("pwd").value;
        //window.alert('here inside ajaxFunction'+vconf+' '+vseid);
  if(xmlhttp) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET","check_login?eid="+ veid +"&pwd="+ vpwd,true); //this is the servlet name
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(null);
  }
}


    function def()
    {
        //window.alert('hi');
        ajaxFunction();            
        //alert('res:'+res);
        if(res=='y')
       {               
                    return true;
       }
       else
       {
                    document.getElementById("uhidden").style.color="#CC0000";
                    document.getElementById("uhidden").innerHTML="Invalid E-Mail ID or Password"
                    return false;                        
       }
    }
```

But the code works only after two clicks :( 
Any help guys?

Comment: my first guess is that your server-side script is setting a cookie to login but...page isn't reloading w/ an ajax call so cookie doesn't actually take effect until next time around

Comment: Did you try debugging the code (firebug?)? It looks like the xmlhttp object is null during the first invocation. How is the method invocation done.? (Button click \ page submit)

Answer (score 1):

Your `def` function calls `ajaxFunction` and then straight away checks the `res` variable. However `ajaxFunction` just sends the AJAX request; it does not wait for the AJAX response to arrive. Your code is checking the `res` variable before it is being set from the AJAX response.

This is why it works on the second click - not because the `res` variable is being set by the second click's AJAX response, but because it is still set from the first click's AJAX response.

The solution is to re-arrange your code a bit. Move the code to display the invalid login message to where the AJAX response is received. In other words, replace the `res=xmlhttp.responseText;` line with some code to check if `xmlhttp.responseText` is not `y` and display the invalid login message.

Comment: Acknowledged the help , but consider a different scenario in reusing the method ajaxFunction(url) when using the same set of variables, including the global var res;, is it possible to invoke several ajax calls from the same function provided that the global variable doesn't affect the two click problem.  In other words, is it possible to reuse the method specified above without rearranging the code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you call def()

Your Request ist asynchron(because you set the 3rd argument of open() to **true** ), but in def() you immediately after sending the request work with the the result:

```
ajaxFunction();            
//alert('res:'+res);
if(res=='y')
```

At this time the request usually is not finished, the result not available yet

Put all code that has to work with the server-response into handleServerResponse()